# Geting file-names from the current working directory

Tags: c#, file, file-system

The following routine returns the file-names from the current working directory:

```
    public static List<string> GetRelativeFileNamesInTheCurrentDirectory(string[] extensions)
    {
        string curr = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(curr);

        List<string> filesList = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            FileInfo temp = new FileInfo(files[i]);

            foreach (var item in extensions)
            {
                if (temp.Extension == item)
                {
                    filesList.Add(temp.Name);
                }
            }
        }

        return filesList;
    }
```

Even though it works, I am not satisfied with the source code's arrangement.

How can I improve it?

Comment: What about a single line: `return new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory).EnumerateFiles().Where(file => extensions.Contains(file.Extension)).Select(file => file.Name).ToList();`?

Answer (score 8):

There are a staggering number of ways to achieve what you want.  Before we get to that, let's have a quick critque of your code.

- You should have a `using System.IO;`
- Names do not need to be overly abbreviated.  E.g. `curr` could be `current` or `currentDirectory`.
- `temp` should be named `file`.
- Your input signature is rigid in that only a string array is allowed.
- Overall, the method you wrote is extremely specific as that the input must be an array, only the current directory is searched, and only a List is returned.

One philosophy I have adopted is to make code into smaller, more manageable methods that (1) favor flexibility over rigidity, and (2) can be re-used for more than the original specific use.

To show you just 1 of many alternatives, let's look at my many changes for smaller code.

I use `EnumerateFiles` instead of `GetFiles`.  This could possibly be more performant, but it since it uses low memory, that is a full array is not materialized with IEnumerable, then you have more options with LINQ, etc.

The input parameter is now `IEnumerable<string>`.  It could be an array, a list, a sorted list, etc.

Since you may repeatedly query the extensions, I think it works best as a **HashSet**.  And, you want that to be a **case-insensitive HashSet** since you should treat ".txt", ".TXT", and ".Txt" as the same.

I return a `List<FileInfo>` because I have taken the time to fetch that and do not want to throw away some possible useful information.  If I want a file name, then I can easily get that file name.

I can have shorter code thanks to LINQ.

My alternative:

```
public static IEnumerable<FileInfo> EnumerateFilesRelativeToCurrentDirectory(IEnumerable<string> fileExtensions)
           => EnumerateFilesRelativeToDirectory(new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()), fileExtensions);

public static IEnumerable<FileInfo> EnumerateFilesRelativeToDirectory(DirectoryInfo directory, IEnumerable<string> fileExtensions)
{
    IEnumerable<FileInfo> files = new List<FileInfo>();

    HashSet<string> allowedExtensions = fileExtensions.ToHashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    if (allowedExtensions.Count == 1)
    {
        files = directory.EnumerateFiles("*" + fileExtensions.First());
    }
    else if (allowedExtensions.Count > 1)
    {
        files = directory.EnumerateFiles().Where(file => allowedExtensions.Contains(file.Extension));
    }

    return files;
}

public static void EnumerateFilesExample()
{
    var fileExtensions = new List<string>() { ".txt", ".csv", ".json" };

    // You can foreach over streamingfiles without regard to Count of index/position.
    // If you want just the name and path, use the FileInfo.Name property.
    // If you want the whole path, use the FileInfo.FullName property.
    var streamingFiles = EnumerateFilesRelativeToCurrentDirectory(fileExtensions);

    // If you demand a Count or want to use positional index, then convert to a list.
    var listOfFiles = EnumerateFilesRelativeToCurrentDirectory(fileExtensions).ToList();

    // If you truly just want a list of the file names, you can use:
    var filenames = EnumerateFilesRelativeToCurrentDirectory(fileExtensions)
                    .Select(file => file.Name)
                    .OrderBy(name => name.ToLower())
                    .ToList();  
}
```

The method to filter by file extension now accepts different types of inputs and can be used against more than just the current directory.  But I also have a convenient method to just check the current directory.  And I do not need to materialize anything to a full list until I absolutely need it (and I would even question if I truly needed to ToList() it before doing so).

**UPDATE**

If you want the shortest, simplest of code, my earliest version to you (since edited) was:

```
public static IEnumerable<FileInfo> EnumerateFilesRelativeToDirectory(DirectoryInfo directory, IEnumerable<string> fileExtensions)
{
    HashSet<string> allowedExtensions = fileExtensions.ToHashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    return directory.EnumerateFiles().Where(file => allowedExtensions.Contains(file.Extension));
}
```

One may note, such as @iSR5 in a comment below, that I use a `return` instead of `yield return` as one would expect for a method returning `IEnumerable`.  I am under the impression for many years that there is a special use case where `return` is preferred.  I have tried to find some authoritative link somewhere to backup my contention, but all I found was this SO answer from @LBushkin back in 2010:

[Is there ever a reason to not use 'yield return' when returning an IEnumerable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3856650/2152078)

I also believe there is a limitation with using only `return` instead of `yield return`: you may only use it **once**, and there can be no other `yield break` or `yield return` used within the method.

Comment: you could simplify `EnumerateFilesRelativeToDirectory` by using `yield return` to reduce memory allocation. something like https://codeshare.io/0gOXZD

Comment: @iSR5 Thanks for the comment.  I have updated my answer to explain why I use `return`.

Comment: if SE could give a chance of double voting, I wouldn't hesitate of given it to you.

Comment: @iSR5 Thanks but if they allowed double voting, they would also allow double down-voting too.

Comment: hard to argue that. but thanks, it made my day ;).

Comment: +1; there's nothing exciting about `return`ing in an `IEnumerale` returning method: it's just a normal method in that case. A `yield break` or `yield return` statement changes the whole method to an iterator, and would be unnecessary in your example. `return`ing in such a case may be preferable in terms of performance (because resources may be relinquished and the returned object may not actually be lazy); `yield`ing may provide a better debugging experience; I'd prefer to `return` because it is simpler and guarantees there is nothing else yielded 'above'.

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite the code a bit.
We use `DirectoryInfo`, which will issue `FileInfo`.
We also use the `EnumerateFiles` method so as not to store the intermediate result, since we do not need it.

```
static List<string> GetRelativeFileNamesInTheCurrentDirectory(string[] extensions)
{
    var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());

    var files = new List<string>();

    foreach (var fileInfo in dirInfo.EnumerateFiles())
    {
        foreach (var item in extensions)
        {
            if (fileInfo.Extension == item)
            {
                files.Add(fileInfo.Name);
            }
        }
    }

    return files;
}
```

---

Look at modern [File globbing in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/file-globbing).

```
static List<string> GetRelativeFileNamesInTheCurrentDirectory(string[] extensions)
{
    string curr = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    
    var patterns = extensions.Select(x => "*" + x);

    Matcher matcher = new();
    matcher.AddIncludePatterns(patterns);

    var files = matcher.GetResultsInFullPath(curr);

    return files.Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x)).ToList();
}
```